# Using 'if in' with a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't believe it, but I've been stumped by what should be a very simple task.

I need to check if a value is in a dictionary as ***either*** key or value. I can find keys using `if 'A' in dictionary`, however I can't seem to get this to work for `values`. I realise I could use a for loop to do this and I may resort to this but I was wondering if there is a built in method for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `in` operator and `any` function like this

```
value in dictionary or any(value in dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)
```

Here, `value in dictionary` makes sure that the expression is evaluated to be Truthy if the `value` is one of the keys of `dictionary`

```
any(value in dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)
```

This part makes sure that, the `value` being searched is in any of the values in the dictionary.

**Note:** This approach is very efficient because

1. you don't have to create any additional list in the memory
2. `any` function short circuits, immediately after finding a match.

If you want to make sure that the value being searched should be exactly matched, then you can change the `in` to `==` like this

```
value in dictionary or any(value == dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)
```

[As DSM Suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744903/using-if-in-with-a-dictionary/22744932#comment34668409_22744932), it would be better if we use `value in dict.itervalues()` in Python 2.x, `value in dict.values()` in Python 3.x

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong. I believe this is the most efficient way.

Comment: @Wooble I was already updating it. Please check the last two lines.

Comment: @Wooble Also OP hasn't specified anything about the type of keys and values.

Comment: @Wooble I knew that somebody would downvote with that exact reason, thats why I have included a way to fix that as well :)

Comment: Well, considering all of the other answers don't use the constant-time check for the key that dicts give you and do an extra O(n) operation, this is definitely the best answer.

Comment: I don't think your first answer using `in` matches what the OP is looking for, and instead of `any(value == dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)` wouldn't it be simpler to write `value in dictionary.itervalues()` in Python 2 or `value in dictionary.values()` in 3?  Why use `any` with a genexp?

Answer (score 3):

two easy ways:

```
my_keys = my_dict.keys()
```

`my_keys` is a list so you can then check for membership

```
my_values = my_dict.values()
```

same

```
if some_thing in my_keys
if some_thing in my_values
```

Of course you don't have to do that with keys though because with keys you can just ask

```
if some_thing in my_dict
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for `d.values()`

`d.keys()` is a list of `dict` keys (though what you were doing originally does the trick for keys)

`d.values()` is a list of the `dict` values. (You can test these for membership.)

where `d` is your `dict`

You can treat these as normal lists

There is also:

```
d.items()
```

which is a list of tuples in the form `(key, value)` for each `dict` entry

**example:**

```
[(key, value), (key, value) ... ]
```

So testing for membership in `d.keys()` and `d.values()` with `in` is simple

With `d.items()` you could do:

```
for pair in d.items():
    if "A" in pair:
        do your thing
```

There is also `d.iteritems()` which you would use with `for` loop and I urge you to google.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following - i.e. combine all the `keys`, and the `values` within the dictionary into a new list and use the `in` keyword to find if value exists in it or not:

```
dict = {"a" : "b", "c" : "d"}

value = "b"

if value in dict.keys() + dict.values():
    print "present"
else: 
    print "absent"
```

You can optimize this further to the following, so that you use the in-built `O(1)` check for keys (from @Wooble's comment), and look for dictionary values only if the it is not in the keys

```
if value in dict or value in dict.values():
    print "present"
```

`